# Rounded list items with padding in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, html-lists

Is there any way to have a jquery list with all list items rounded at all corners, and to have padding like space between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `data-inset="true"` attribute to the `ul` tag with `data-role="listview"` and with these styles:

```
​.ui-listview li { 
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 1em;
}

.ui-listview {
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}​
```

See the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xgaJt/2/).